# How do I use a nested attribute with a form_for 's select method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, rhtml

We have a `user` model which `:has_one detail`.  In a `form_for` a user, I want a drop-down to select the user's details' `time_zone`.

I've tried

```
<% form_for @user do |f| %>
    ... user stuff ...

    <%= f.select :"detail.time_zone", ...other args... %>
<% end %>
```

but I get a `NoMethodError` for detail.time_zone.  What's the correct syntax for doing this - or if it's not possible to do it this way, how should I be doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget to use [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) in your user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :detail
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :detail
end
```

Detail model:

```
class Detail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Users controller:

```
class UsersController < ActionController::Base
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.build_detail
  end
end
```

User new/edit view:

```
<% form_for @user do |u| %>
  <% u.fields_for :detail do |d| %>
    <%= d.select :country, Country.all.map { |c| [c.name, c.id] }
    <%= d.time_zone_select :time_zone %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is there a colon after `f.select`? Also it should be `<%=...` and not `<%..`

Assuming you have a 'time_zone' column in your table,

```
<% form_for @user do |f| %>
    ... user stuff ...
    
    # args: user object, time_zone method, prioritizing zones(separating list), default
    <%= f.time_zone_select :time_zone, nil, :default => "Pacific Time (US & Canada)", :include_blank => false %>
<% end %>
```

Additional resource :

> http://railscasts.com/episodes/106-time-zones-in-rails-2-1
>
> http://railsontherun.com/2007/12/21/timezone-selection/

Comment: Fixed the equals.  Thanks for the pointer to time_zone_select.  Your example doesn't work, though, because time_zone doesn't belong to user, it belongs to user.detail.  How do I specify that?